# Scikit-learn, random forests - How many samples does each tree contain?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

In scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier, there is no setting to specify how many samples each tree should be built from. That is, how big the subsets should be that are randomly pulled from the data to build each tree.

I'm having trouble finding how many samples scikit-learn pulls by default. Does anyone know?

Comment: Have you found any compelling answers yet? I am also looking into this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347818/number-of-samples-per-tree-in-a-random-forest

Answer (score 1):

I believe RandomForestClassier will use the entire training set to build each tree. Typically building each tree involves selecting the features which have the most predictive power(the ones which create the largest 'split'), and having more data makes computing that more accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Can anyone confirm or deny that the entire training set is used to build each tree?